# Angular Directive scope binding not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working with Angular for a while. However, today I found it quite weird that the attrs in my custom directive were not bound correctly. Here is the excerpt of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <io-map geo-location-x="item.data.x" geo-location-y="item.data.y" zoom-level="item.data.zoom"></io-map>
</div>

angular.directive('io-map', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      geoLocationX:'=',
      geoLocationY:'=',
      zoomLevel:'='
    },
    template: '<div id="map-' + Math.round(Math.random()*100000000) + '" style="height:400px"></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //Some logic...
      //I checked the attrs here, and found attrs.geoLocationX and so on are just plain strings like "item.data.x", meaning they are not bound, while I can assure you that item.data.x has its value.
    }
  }
})
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use `attrs` if you are binding in with `=`?  You already should have access to the value using `scope.geoLocationX` and then the 2-way binding will work without any `$watch`.

Comment: @DavinTryon I just mistook 'scope' for 'attrs'. You're right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using isolated scope with `=` bindings will not resolve the attribute values using `attrs`.

```
scope: {
  geoLocationX:'=',
  geoLocationY:'=',
  zoomLevel:'='
},
```

You should use the `scope` instead:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //Some logic...
      //use
      var valueForGeoLocationX = scope.geoLocationX;
    }
```

Comment: How careless! If I had met you earlier, hours of debugging would have been saved. :P